# Fluid mesh not visible in the viewport

Tags: modeling, mesh

I wanted to learn hot to create a liquid, so I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/JYc_6fXEjw4
It all goes well until I change the viewport and seeing that it didn't create a mesh to see te liquid.
So I watched until the end and I did a small render and I still don't see it.

Blender 2.83 clearly shows that there is a liquid, it plays the liquid, but you can't see the mesh.
I baked the mesh and all. So, I don't know how to make the mesh visible.
This is the blend file that I used to test it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gLDsggzxpaQGan-bwxVBS5eOGrVim2i5/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Use stable versions only.

Comment: I tried that first on 2.82 but since it didn't work I switched to 2.83

Comment: Nvm, after a while redoing it, it just happens